# query in controller in dockerized laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i dockerized my laravel project (9.25.1) and my problem is my query in tinker totally works and `php artisan migrate` works too but when i query in controller i get mysql error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - 4306:3306
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=4306
DB_DATABASE=main
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

Comment: change DB_HOST to db: `DB_HOST=db` and port to `3306`

Comment: @Maksim it works but why 4306 not works and php artisan migrated was working with 4306

Comment: RTFM docker networking. This is because containers can reach other containers in private network where hostnames is container names. Migrate working because you pass db port to your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/). If your application will run in a docker container, you need to use internal port. In your scenario it's `3306`. If you want to use tinker run it on docker container.

For example:

```
docker-compose exec main php artisan tinker
```

For other artisan commands:

```
docker-compose exec main php artisan migrate
```